# correct way to register a regulator in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

im working on a kernel driver for the Texas instruments [tps92518-Q1](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS92518-Q1) and [tps92518HV-Q1](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS92518HV-Q1)

an am unsure of the "correct" way to register the regulator

so far I've found three possibilities

1. regulator_register() from [/drivers/regulator/core.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/drivers/regulator/core.c#L5305)
2. devm_regulator_register() from [/drivers/regulator/devres.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/drivers/regulator/devres.c#L175)
3. platform_device_register() from [/drivers/base/platform.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15/source/drivers/base/platform.c#L762)

regulator_register() is described in kernel docs regulator [api reference](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/regulator.html#api-reference) but is only used by [two drivers](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=regulator_register%28%29)

devm_regulator_register() is used by [various existing drivers](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=devm_regulator_register%28%29)

platform_device_register() is described in  [linux/Documentation/power/regulator/machine.rst](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/7246f4dcaccc8de76a96a41359d89c3c791579bc/Documentation/power/regulator/machine.rst) but only seem to be used in [one driver](https://github.com/search?q=platform_device_register()%20%20repo%3Atorvalds%2Flinux%20path%3Adrivers%2Fregulator%2F&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=&l=)

Comment: AFAICS it is a LED controller, so the proper location is _drivers/leds_. Hence it should register a LED.

Comment: i was thinking it was something like the [tps6105x](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS61050) ( linux/drivers/mfd/tps6105x.c ), but a dual version, and should register as a mfd with both regulator and led components and would end up effectively registering two regulators and two "LEDs"

Comment: the regulator part manages the min/max current constraints and the led part manages brightness, if done buy the device,

Comment: @0andriy also the way i am intending to use it is as a current regulator to a [matrix led controller](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS92662-Q1?keyMatch=TPS92662-Q1) so wouldn't control the LEDs directly, which TI recommend this controller for.